# Make 2 urls equivalent with .htaccess and serve it as RSS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rss

I have link that looks like this:

```
mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=2:rss1klik&format=feed&Itemid=160
```

That link serves what's supposed to be RSS 2.0 but it serves it as plain text instead of RSS.

I'd like to turn that first link into this:

```
mydomain.com/index.php/rss/rss1klik
```

And also make server send headers that tells browser that it's `RSS` not `PlainText`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using use this rule in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^rss/rss1klik/?$ /index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=2:rss1klik&format=feed&Itemid=160 [T=application/rss+xml,NC,L,QSA]
```